# Can't keep Wordpress from generating thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

What I want is to prevent Wordpress from generating thumbnail images (additional sizes) when Media uploader in admin is used or when *wp_generate_attachment_metadata()* + *wp_update_attachment_metadata()* is used.

To do so I have set *Thumbnail size, Medium size and Large size* to 0 - 0 in *Settings/Media* in admin menu. However, Wordpress still keeps generating these additional size images.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `functions.php`:

```
// Prevent WordPress from generating additional image sizes
function shapeSpace_customize_image_sizes($sizes) {
    unset($sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset($sizes['medium']);
    unset($sizes['medium_large']);
    unset($sizes['large']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'shapeSpace_customize_image_sizes');
add_filter('max_srcset_image_width', create_function('', 'return 1;'));
```

Works for me. You'll end up with only original image uploaded to WordPress through Media Library.

Comment: Note that your theme can also generate its own custom image sizes. You'll have to disable them too if so.

Answer (score 0):

Try in theme's functions.php:

wordpress-folder/wp-content/themes/theme-name/functions.php

a line looking like :

```
add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true );
```

and also:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );
```

remove the lines, or uncomment them if you're not sure.

Hope that works together with what you already made.